# Advanced Custom Fields File Download

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a bilingual website which is using advanced custom fields and wpglobus as a bilingual asset. The custom post page has a download file button which downloads a pdf in English every time even if the website is in French. I have the same pdf in both English and French

How can I enable a French file download when the website is in French using ACF ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ACF will have the French & English files stored separately with a unique key. You can write a conditional using the `WPGlobus::Config()->language` method to determine which file to serve up. Something like:

```
echo (WPGlobus::Config()->language === 'fr' ? get_field('fr_file_key') : get_field('en_file_key'));
```

or if you prefer:

```
if( WPGlobus::Config()->language === 'fr' ) {
    the_field('fr_file_key');
} else { 
    the_field('en_file_key');
}
```

Try this (per your comment):

```
<?php if( WPGlobus::Config()->language === 'fr' ) : ?> 
    <a href="<?php the_sub_field('pdf_file'); ?>" target="_blank">Download</a> 
<?php else : ?> 
    <a href="<?php the_sub_field('pdf_en_file'); ?>" target="_blank">Download</a> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You're not writing the PHP correctly. I've updated my answer, try the new code posted.

Comment: Worked. Thank You

Comment: The front end is showing the change but in the back end it is still displaying the same text and files for both the English and French text boxes.
Is it an ACF issue or the WPGlobus issue. 

The content is fully bilingual in the front end but the admin panel only shows the text and files in English even though there are two tabs for each English and French option.

Comment: Hmm sounds like it might be a compatibility issue between the plugins. The documentation for WPGlobus says it supports ACF... maybe want to contact the developer about that one.